# Join strings in a block

Tags: swift, string, swift-block

I have a block that updates the view for each String. In its object class I pass it by:

```
func eachFeaturesSection(block: ((String?) -> Void)?) {
propertyFeatures.forEach { feature in
  guard let feature = feature as? RealmString else {
    return
  }
  let features = feature.stringValue
    block?(features)
 }
}
```

and I will get it in `ViewController`, by:

```
listing!.eachFeaturesSection({ (features) in
  print(features)
  self.facilities = features!
})
```

So it will print as:

```
Optional("String 1")
Optional("String 2")
```

and self.facilities will be set to latest value which is `self.facilities = "String 2"`

```
cell.features.text = features // it will print String 2
```

So, how can I achieve to join all strings together in one string such as `self.facilities = "String 1, String 2"`. I used .jointString does not work. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could add them to an array of `String` elements and then, when done, call `joined` on that array.

So something like this in your ViewController:

```
var featuresArray = [String]()

listing!.eachFeaturesSectionT({ (features) in
    print(features)
    featuresArray.append(features!)
})

//Swift 3 syntax
cell.features.text = featuresArray.joined(separator: ", ")

//Swift 2 syntax
cell.features.text = featuresArray.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you. But it gives error saying "Value of type '[String]' has no member 'joined' in this line: cell.features.text = featuresArray.joined(separator: ", ")

Comment: Yes this worked! featuresArray.joinWithSeparator(", ")

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

`self.facilities = features!` is doing nothing but keeps updating the value every iteration

Change the line `self.facilities = features!` to `self.facilities += features!` or `self.facilities = self.facilities + ", " +  features!`

Comment: Thanks. This one: "self.facilities = self.facilities + features!" works! but it prints like, String1String2. Any way to seperate them with a comma in this implementation.

Comment: self.facilities = self.facilities + ", " + features! , have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it (assuming your `propertyFeatures` is an array of `RealmString`):

Swift 3:

```
let string = (propertyFeatures.map { $0.stringValue }).joined(separator: ", ")
```

Swift 2:

```
let string = (propertyFeatures.map { $0.stringValue }).joinWithSeparator(", ")
```